# How do I create a log4j Logger using Spring XML configuration?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

How do I create a log4j Logger using Spring XML configuration?

I would like to do something like this so I can inject the logger into other instances:

```
<bean id="logger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger">
    <property name="logName" value="my.Logger" />
</bean>
```

Comment: My very personal opinion: I dislike this approach as I'm used to take advantage of the log4j flexibility of enabling and disabling logging for specific packages (while developing). And I'd look into   [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) while you're at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [construct beans via static methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) using the factory-method attribute.  So for log4j we can use the static [`Logger.getLogger()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29) method to construct a bean:

```
<bean id="logger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="my.Logger" />
</bean>
```